# Update server side control while exporting Crystal report using exporttohttpresponse to reponse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using the following code to create a Crystal report after pressing an ASP button on my webpage:

```
label1.text = now.tostring()
oRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "Ticket")
```

The label doesn't get updated because the full postback is stopped by the download request. I use that label to update some database entries and can't get it to persist. Do I have to use a session variable to store the date or is there some known workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the **multi-Threading**, separating into two processes, one for update `label1.Text` (run as **BackgroundWorker**) and another for export the report. Final, let them parallel run.

As you used VB.Net, here is sample code:

```
Sub UpdateDate()
    ...
    Label1.Text = now.ToString()
End Sub
Sub ExportReport()
    ...
    oRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "Ticket")
End Sub
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf UpdateDate)
    Thread1.IsBackground = True
    Thread1.Start()

    Dim Thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ExportReport)
    Thread2.Start()
End Sub
```

Don't forget to import needed namspace

```
Imports System.Threading
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't help. The page is not refreshing so I'm not sure how the extra thread would help that.

Comment: Why do you want the page to refresh by itself inspite you have a button to start update label and export report? Now I'm not sure what your concept, seems you want the page refresh automatically to run those tasks, is'n it? Otherwise, please descript me more, thanks.